# 2048 Webgame bot

Tags: python, beginner, selenium, 2048

So there is this game 2048. You can play it [here](https://play2048.co/)

I wrote a python script which "plays" the game on the website by clicking the arrow keys.

I would like to know what can be improved.
Is it a good idea to check the Try again button with exceptions? Is there a better way?

Currently it takes alot of tries to get a high score for the bot. Can the logic be improved?

**play_2048.py**

```
"""
Opens the webpage of the 2048 game and plays it repeadly.
Needs chromedriver in the directory of the script. Download it here:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
"""

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def play_2048():
    """
    Main lopp of script. First opens the browser to the game page.
    Then pushes the arrow keys to play the game.
    If a game over occurs the try again button on the page is klicked
    to repeat the game
    """
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://play2048.co/')

    html = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

    while True:
        html.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
        html.send_keys(Keys.UP)
        html.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
        html.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

        try:
            retry = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Try again')
        except:
            continue
        else:
            retry.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_2048()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really much here to comment on, since there isn't even AI involved.

The only thing that stands out to me is your use of a silent "catch-all" `try` block:

```
try:
    retry = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Try again')

except: # Big problem here
    continue

else:
    retry.click()
```

You're catching every exception, and simply ignoring them. In this *particular* case the ramifications aren't huge. Say in the future though you add a second function to do some processing and decide to put it in the `try` (for whatever reason). Something like:

```
try:
    retry = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Try again')
    do_something_with_retry(retry) # This throws. Would you ever know that though?

except:
    continue

else:
    retry.click()
```

And lets say that `do_something_with_retry` is improperly tested, or some unforeseen circumstance comes up, and suddenly `do_something_with_retry` starts throwing exceptions. Would you ever even know that there was an exception thrown? How would you debug your code failing in that case? It would be *much* better to be specific about what you need to catch, and deal with that only. As you can see in the [API
 documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text), `find_element_by_link_text` is documented to throw a `NoSuchElementException` if something fails. Catch that instead, so irrelevant errors aren't silently ignored as well:

```
try:
    retry = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Try again')

except NoSuchElementException as e: # Be specific!
    continue

else:
    retry.click()
```

Now anything other than a `NoSuchElementException` will cause your program to crash. *This is a good thing though*. You don't want fundamentally broken code to run.

Don't make your code vulnerable to silly mistakes that may happen in the future. Silly mistakes happen (like improperly tested functions). It's best that they fail catastrophically so they can be detected and fixed.

Of course though, the better option to handling the addition of `do_something_with_retry` would be, if possible, to just not group it in the `try` in the first place. Again though, mistakes happen.

---

As for

> Currently it takes alot of tries to get a high score for the bot. Can the logic be improved?

That involves writing up an AI to play the game, and is no small feat. That would be beyond the scope of a Code Review unfortunately.

Comment: if i define `name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined` it is not defined

Comment: @Sandro4912 You need to import it from selenium. That's not a standard exception.

Comment: it worked by adding `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 1):

A first step towards writing an AI is to give this an interface.

First, let's rewrite the "AI" you are currently using as a class:

```
from itertools import cycle

class Cycler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cycle = cycle([Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP, Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN])

    def next(self, *args):
        return next(self.cycle)
```

Which you can use like this in your current code:

```
ai = Cycler()
while True:
    html.send_keys(ai.next())
    try:
        ...
```

In the future you might want to be smarter than that and for that you would need the state of the board to be passed along to the AI.

```
Class GameStatePrinter(Cycler):
    def next(self, game_state, *args):
        print(game_state)
        return super(self, GameStatePrinter).next(*args)
```

This is not really any smarter, but you can pass it the current game state and it will print it:

```
ai = GameStatePrinter()
while True:
    current_state = get_current_state(html)
    html.send_keys(ai.next(current_state))
    ...
```

An actual smart bot would then of course act differently according to the information in the board, whereas this one just does the same thing as `Cycler`, which it inherits from.

This logic is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: i tryed adding the first part but in the line `self.cycle = cycle[Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP, Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN]` it throws `'type' object is not subscriptable` so maybe the keys don't work with cycler

Comment: @Sandro4912: You missed the parenthesis around the list, it should be `self.cycle = cycle([Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP, Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN])`